# Start video at vertical scroll point, then play in reverse

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to achieve something with html5 video and haven't been able to find an answer elsewhere. Is it possible? Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the html:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" poster="http://dummyimage.com/320x240/ffffff/fff">
    <source src="videos/ship.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I want to:
    - on page load, display the video paused on the first frame (use poster?)
    - at vertical scroll of X pixels, play the video once through (alternatively, inject it onto the page at X scroll?)
    - then, when I scroll back beyond the X pixels value play the video again in reverse once through (does this work aMediaElement.playbackRate = -1; ?)

Answer (score 0):

sadly the simplest solution `playbackRate = -1` doesn't seem to be implemented anywhere yet.

you could fake it with some code like below to jump the `currentTime` back at whatever rate you need but from playing around it doesn't look very smooth.

my suggestion would be - if practical - to actually encode a a reversed version of the video if being able to play it backwards is the goal and then swap the source or toggle the visible `<video>` tag

Oh, and as usual... any video you're planning to stream on the web make sure you optimize and get the `moov` atom in the right place (see [sample ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351136/preparing-mp4-file-for-html-5/27362604#27362604))

```
<script>
var intervalRewind = 0;
var v = document.getElementById("v")

function rewind() {
    intervalRewind = setInterval(
        function(){
            v.playbackRate = 1.0;
            if(v.currentTime == 0){
                clearInterval(intervalRewind);
                v.pause();
            } else {
                v.currentTime += -.1;
            }
        },30);
}            
</script>
```

...

```
<video id="v" onclick="clearInterval(intervalRewind)" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video-fs.mp4" />
</video>

<button onclick="rewind()">Rewind</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, the playbackRate option isn't doing it. Was wondering if I was just doing it wrong! Thanks so much for the feedback - I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: looks like playbackRate only works on a couple of browsers, and only for positive values. Shame really. the kludge about looks pretty horrid (buffers way too often for me to be happy with it!)