# cross-platform syntax for mp4 embedded in html5

Tags: android, html, internet-explorer, video, ffmpeg

The code below produces a properly embedded video in `firefox`, but does not display properly in `internet explorer` or in `android`.  I have all my browsers set to automatically update, so they are all always running the most current versions.

```
In `internet explorer`, the code below leaves a large blank space where the  
video should be.  The user has to hover over the large blank space before the  
controls become visible.  

In `android`, the code below produces an unusable/unclickable area, and the  
user has to greatly zoom the focus to get the small start button to become  
big enough to click to start the video.  

However, in `firefox`, the code below shows the first frame of the video,  
which you can click to start the video.
```

**How can I change the code below to get all three of these browsers to show the first frame when the page loads, and for the video to be start-able when the user clicks on the first frame?**

Here is [a link to the video file on a file sharing site](https://jumpshare.com/b/w7sZMSBSFJZnlTV3gJMi).

Here is the `ffmeg` code for processing the video:

```
ffmpeg -y -i SourceFile.mp4 -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -b 3M -strict -2 -movflags faststart DestFile.mp4
```

Thanks to [offbeatmammal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1569675/offbeatmammal) for getting me this far.
Here is the `html5` code for embedding the video in a web page browser:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
    <source src="somefile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: which versions of IE and Android are you trying? worked okay for me, though by default browsers won't might not show the first frame, so you'd want to use the `poster` attribute on the `video` tag

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I am using version 11.0.9600 of internet explorer.  Oddly, the problem is slightly different when hosted on localhost than when hosted on AWS.  I will look into the poster attribute when I have time to revisit this personal project. I will check my android version and get back to you.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal My android phone says the version numbers for the internet app and for the html viewer app are both 2.3.6.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I do not want to limit it to what works on my phone.  I want it to work in as broad a range of environments as possible.  It would be nice if it could show the first frame instead of some other image named in the poster attribute.

Comment: your phone is pretty old, the Android browser there is not Chrome and not that up to date. Using the <video> tag with the poster image is going to be the most reliable. Is the videos are large (per the comment in the answer below) preloading the video will be a pretty horrid experience

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thank you again.  I will try this over the weekend and get back to you.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal The `poster` attribute did force the `jpg` to be visible on-screen so the user can see where the video is.  It does this in `internet explorer` and on my old `android` phone.  But still you have to click on the video start button to start the video in those 2 browsers, instead of just clicking anywhere on the image like you can in `firefox`.  Is there some way to make it so that users of all 3 browsers can start the video simply by clicking anywhere on the `poster` image?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Android browsers require some special handling to support MPEG-4/H.264 video format:

http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/

You can also set the preload property of the video element to "auto" to preload the video via javascript once the page loads:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video").preload = "auto";
```

Comment: This video is on a page that has many other videos that together total a couple gigabytes.  All the videos have the same problem in android and in internet explorer.  If I preload as you suggest, I could burn out a visitor's entire monthly data allowance each time they open the page.  Not do mention simply locking their browsers up waiting for long downloads.  Do you know a way to simply have the first frame be visible along with working controls for starting the video, ideally by just clicking anywhere in the first frame?

Comment: I'm trying to speculate that it might have something to do with how you have encoded the video. I saw something in the net pertaining to faststart but its vague. Can you try removing the faststart switch in ffmeg?