# html5 video safari downloads full before playing

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, progressive

Im wondering why my mp4 html5 video is not "streaming" and instead waits till it is fully downloaded before it starts playing in safari.

www.pija.se

I have tried QTIndexSwapper but it says the index is in the right position.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like the MOOV atom isn't at the beginning of the file.
I used ffmpeg to just relocate that (no other encoding) and then a binary compare (using [HexFiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/)) and a quick test seemed to show that Safari was playing the video sooner

```
./ffmpeg -i top.mp4 -codec copy -movflags faststart top-fs.mp4
```

(caveat being that even though I cleared browser cache I didn't do things like bounce my test server or time things too accurately)

FWIW I find ffmpeg to be a good solution, and especially for background video you'll want to [play around with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351136/preparing-mp4-file-for-html-5/27362604#27362604) to optimize for your use-case

Comment: Thank you. Yes it starts earlier now but I have also made the file smaller so not sure how to test it it stream or not or just downloads faster :) .

Comment: I have the same question. How can I analyze a video to see where it's components are? Does ffmpeg do this as well?