# Forcing playback with short HTML5 videos in Safari

Tags: javascript, video, safari, webkit, html5-video

I've been running into issues with Safari and the `<video>` element in combination with shorter high-quality videos. For a showcase website I'm loading 12-15 second `.mp4` and `.webm` files into a `<video>` container using the `<source>` element. When trying to play the video in Chrome it works flawlessly and the video start playing almost instantaneously, but Safari appears to want to load the video completely before starting playback.

I have looked into loading the video directly through the `src` attribute of `<video>` and have also added the `preload="auto"` attribute in an attempt to force immediate playback.

I've set up an example using one of the videos we use on the websites, which is around 8 MB and 12 seconds long: https://jsfiddle.net/n1eac46v/

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var source = document.createElement('source');

source.src = "foo.mp4";
source.type = "video/mp4";

video.appendChild(source);
video.on("canplay canplaythrough", video.play);
```

As you can see I'm also listening for the `canplay` and the `canplaythrough` events, but even that doesn't appear to help. I've been looking all over the place for days on end but am running out of options now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an OS X user so I have no experience with Safari, however I've had the chance to debug mp4 playback in Chrome. Chrome has a buffering window that it tries to fill until it begins actual playback. Safari may have a bigger window. Also since in normal cases all the tables that contain sample positions, durations etc. are at the end of the file browser may want to read them to begin playback. A smart browser can dispatch a read with a byte range header to get only the end of the file and then seek the actual video data, but again I have no idea what safari does.

What you can try is to use [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) on your video files to move the meta data and all tables to the beginning, that could help.

As mentioned by OP in the comments using FFmpeg with `-movflags faststart` (see [FFmpeg MP4 options](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mov_002c-mp4_002c-ismv)) can also be used to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! While MP4Box isn't available for OSX quite as easily, your answer took me in the right direction. I ended up using [this answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28512437/3840022) on a related question to solve the issue using just FFMPEG.

`./ffmpeg -i top.mp4 -codec copy -movflags faststart top-fs.mp4`

This moves the flags up to the front like you mentioned and solves the problem, even for shorter videos!

Comment: @Thomas - true, I forgot about FFmpeg:) Glad that it worked. Funny, this is the first time I get accepted with -1 :D