# HTML5 Video tag not playing video in safari untill it is fully downloaded

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari

I am using HTML5 video tag to load video on browser. It is working fine in every browser except safari.

In safari it wait for whole video to download and than starts playing. Whereas all other browser play video while buffering.

I have tried all the possible available solutions from stackoverflow and other also. Mostly I found about **FFMPEG**, and tried it. But nothing is working for me.

Below is the code I am using.

```
<video preload="auto" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: have you used the faststart option in ffmpeg? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503324/html5-video-safari-downloads-full-before-playing/28512437#28512437

Comment: Have you tried `preload="none"`?

Answer (score 0):

The preload attribute is supported in Safari 5.0 and later. Safari on iOS never preloads. May be you should check your browser version.

Comment: I am using Safari on Mac and its version is >11