# Preloading a series of big Videos files

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a function that plays a series of videos. I have only one video tag and I use JS to update the video src to play the next video in the series.  I have now bigger video files and I need to build a video preload function.

Some of the videos are big (100MB) and the total of all videos in the series is too big (150MB) for a function to load entire video files before playing them.

Something like this I like to build:
Have a ha script that can read an array of video url. And start preload them. And then when X % is downloaded the script let me know.

Please help with a smart solution.

Comment: I would suggest having two video elements and once one is playing set the source on the other and let the browser buffer preload, and swap them (there will be a slight pause). Are the videos optimized for streaming (if MP4 is the MOOV atom at the start) and does the server support byte range requests? Other option use fragmented mpeg (HLS or Dash) and build a playlist

Comment: I jus Handbrake and the "Web optimized" but it still take some time for the video to get played. Do I have to do anything else for streaming to work?

Comment: I don't know what handbrake does specifically, but if there's an option to relocate the MOOV atom (metadata) to the front, you should take it. I use ffmpeg (free download) and this command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503324/html5-video-safari-downloads-full-before-playing/28512437#28512437

Comment: Ok. Will check. Is there a way to start preloading at a given point? And can I “see” if the preload has started?

Comment: browser controls what happens (use the `preload='auto'` attribute) and you can watch events eg https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: Ok. Thanks will look at it. In a ideal world I like to have a ha script how can read a array of video url. And start preload them. And then when X% is done let me know.