# html5 video not able to seek video on first load on Google Chrome, but after refresh the page for few times, it able to seek

Tags: google-chrome, wcf, html5-video

html5 video not able to seek video on first load on Google Chrome but works fine one Firefox, but after refresh the page for few times, it able to seek with WCF server.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<body>
<div>       
       <video controls width="320" height="240">
            <source src="https://sync.xxxxxx.biz/api-dev/transferservice.svc/getvideo" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Below is my WCF code

```
public Stream getVideoStream()
        {
            try
            {
                string videoFileFullPath = "c:\\20200423180011.mp4";
                FileStream videoStream = File.OpenRead(videoFileFullPath);

                IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
                foreach (String key in request.Headers.AllKeys) {
                    log.Info("key " + key);
                }
                if (request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Range"))
                {
                    log.Info("Start Range " + request.Headers.Get("Range"));

                    //long startRange = Convert.ToInt64(request.Headers.Get("Range")); // get the start range from the header
                    //videoStream.Position = startRange;
                }

                log.Info(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(videoFileFullPath));
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(videoFileFullPath);
                return videoStream;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new TSException(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please refer to  [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp), also try to show the running code example using any online compiler like JSbin. It also seems like you are using an incorrect link in the src of your above code.

Comment: if it's taking a couple of refreshes to fully load, you'll want to check to see if it's been optimized for streaming (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503324/html5-video-safari-downloads-full-before-playing/28512437#28512437), and that your server supports byte-range requests (which allow faster seeking without having to load the whole file).

Comment: Hi Champion-runner, but I able to play the video on firefox, chrome, just not able to seek the video on chrome.