# how does video buffering work and what is the general architecture look like?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, websocket, streaming

Currently working on a webapp that uses node and react so I am able to use other node modules if needed. I am able to request/send files to the front-end of the app. Files like pdfs/images are relatively quick and user experience is not affected even though they can't view it unless the request is successful. this is an issue for longer videos though If a user cannot play a video  until the request is complete - my longest video is 10-15 minutes and the request can take over a minute on bad connections.

Is this a use case for websockets or am I over-simplifying it?

Comment: depending on video format you may simply not be optimizing. With an MP4 the metadata lives in a thing called the MOOV atom which is usually at the end of the file, so until the whole file it loaded it's not available to the browser. If you move it (using ffmpeg or similar) to the start, and have a server supporting byte range requests, then playback can usually start much faster

Comment: they are mp4 files, I will take a look at that.

Comment: sorry, forgot to include a link to an example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503324/html5-video-safari-downloads-full-before-playing/28512437#28512437

Comment: @makingithappeninc Show us a testable link to a problem video. You can delete the link./ file (make invalid) after getting some advice.