# HTML5 video_tag in rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video

I am in development and trying to load static videos using the html5 video tag, but the video is not displaying, nor playing. This is what I did.

I created a videos sub-directory within the assets folder. I then made this change to my application.rb file;

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
```

From there I set my video_tag using the following:

```
<%= video_tag 'complete_test_variables.mov', size: '320x240', controls: true %>
```

I am not getting any console errors and my logs seem to be showing that I am getting the video okay:

Started GET "/assets/complete_test_variables-8c4a0ecfb07ddab0bf90996f4ee41894f3cdda44025e10ceab9c06bdda2f8e66.mov" for ::1 at 2016-07-05 08:52:29 -0400

I also tried routing directly to the videos file path like so:

```
<%= video_tag '/assets/videos/complete_test_variables.mov', size: '320x240', controls: true %>
```

only I get this error;

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/videos/complete_test_variables.mov"):
```

Can someone suggest why this might not be working, or what I can do to fix the issue?

Or maybe I should stick with golf.

Comment: try with an `.mp4` or `.ogg` or other supported format. `.mov` containers are not supported in most browsers. you can usually test by trying to open the video in the browser directly

Comment: That worked. I used a free video format converter called Zamzar for anyone coming across this. Also @Offbeatmammal if you write and answer, I'll accept it. File format I converted to was mp4, but I'm guessing ogg would work also.

Comment: added as answer, glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with an `.mp4` or `.ogg` or other supported format. `.mov` containers are not supported in most browsers.

You can usually test by trying to open the video in the browser directly.

I'd also suggest reviewing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351136/preparing-mp4-file-for-html-5/27362604#27362604) for some hints on optimizing the video using ffmpeg