# Google Chrome does not autoplay HTML5 video on mobile

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I have problems to get a video to play on my Android mobile in the latest version of Chrome. In other browsers like the Puffin browser the video is playing. For test purposes I tried all common formats:

```
mp4
<br />
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" onended="this.play()"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
<br />
webm
<br />
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" onended="this.play()"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>
<br />
ogg
<br />
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" onended="this.play()"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg" /></video>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozpVNP

[image: QR Code for CodePen]

[image: Preview on mobile]

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) the first video, that is H.264 + AAC in MP4 should play. I also take [this article](https://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) in account and tried to play the videos by JavaScript additionally as well as tried to remove the `type` attribute on the first `video` tag without success.

How can I get it work in Chrome on Mobile?

Comment: if the problem is that it doesn't autoplay, then that's by design for most mobile browsers. If the problem is video not playing have you tried URL directly in browser? May need to re-encode (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351136/preparing-mp4-file-for-html-5/27362604#27362604)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal If I open [the video directly](http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4) I can play it on my mobile in Chrome. And even when Chrome does not support autoplay, why is there no way to play it then?

Comment: what Android device/version of Chrome are you using? If I take your code and add `<video ... controls>` then I see a play button and the mp4 video plays...

Comment: @Offbeatmammal CM13 on LGG4. Yes, adding controls works, but there are two things that annoy me, though. In my case, the video is responsive, and it the videoplayer will have a different size before I finally play it. Also it would be so much greater if it could autoplay.

Comment: autoplay is rightly blocked on mobile. user has to make the decision

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that Google want that users initiate by themselves any media, so If [you debug your device chrome browser](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/), you will get the warning "*Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.*"
So that means you need to attach the video initialization, for example, with a click event

Answer (score 24):

```
<video autoplay loop autobuffer muted playsinline>
     <source src="video/video-hat.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: This worked for me on Chrome on an Android (7) phone.

Comment: Can you explain what role each of these additional attributes play in addressing the issue?

Answer (score 9):

There doesn't appear to be any great info on this, so thought I'd post my findings.

I've been debugging html5 video playback on Chrome desktop and mobile on an Android 5.0.1 Samsung S4 with Chrome 61 and the embedded browser, and Safari 9 & 11, using an automatic javascript play/pause written in AngularJS (below). The video is embedded in a carousel so is sometimes visible, sometimes not. In summary:

- I would recommend having both webm(vp8/vorbis) and mp4(h264/aac) formats. These are the most supported formats and have equivalent quality for the same bitrate. ffmpeg can encode both.
- It seems Chrome mobile prefers webm if it can get it, so put that first.
- If a browser plays a file when you direct it to the file url, this **does not** mean it will play it when embedded in a video tag, though it will tell you if the format & codecs are supported if it does play. Chrome mobile seems very picky about having a video source whose resolution is too high.
- Safari (and probably iOS) **will not** play a video unless served by a server supporting byte-ranges. Apache, nginx and Amazon S3 for example do support them, but many smaller web servers (like WSGI servers) do not.
- The order of the videos matters more than the source `media` attribute. Always have low resolution versions of a video first. The example below uses 1920x1080 and 1280x720. It seems if the mobile browser encounters a video that is "too high-res", it just stops processing the other sources and prefers the poster.
- having a `controls` attribute and manual play vs playing through javascript doesn't appear to make any difference.
- the `muted` attribute stops android from putting a little speaker icon in the status bar when playing but off-screen, even when the video doesn't have audio. As a side-note, I'd also really think about your audience if you intend to autoplay video with sound. Personally I think it's a bad idea.
- the `preload` attribute doesn't seem to make much difference. The browser will tend to automatically preload the selected video metadata anyway.
- having a source `type` attribute does not stop the video from playing. If anything it helps the browser choose which source to pick for the best
- the JS `video.oncanplay` event is the best way to see if the video tag has been successful. If you don't get that, the video won't play, but the browser won't tell you why.

**HTML:**

```
<video class="img-responsive-upscale ng-scope"
  video-auto-ctrl loop muted preload poster="0022.png">
  <source src="vid_small.webm" media="(max-width: 1280px)" type="video/webm">
  <source src="vid_small.mp4" media="(max-width: 1280px)" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="vid.webm" media="(max-width: 1920px)" type="video/webm">
  <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <img src="0022.png" alt="something"
    title="Your browser does not support the <video> tag">
</video>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('myproducts.videoplay', []).directive('videoAutoCtrl',
  function() {
  return {
    require: '^uibCarousel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var video = element[0];
      var canplay = false;
      var rs = ["HAVE_NOTHING", "HAVE_METADATA", "HAVE_CURRENT_DATA", "HAVE_FUTURE_DATA", "HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA"];
      var ns = ["NETWORK_EMPTY", "NETWORK_IDLE", "NETWORK_LOADING", "NETWORK_NO_SOURCE"];

      function vinfo() {
        console.log("currentSrc = " + video.currentSrc);
        console.log("readyState = " + rs[video.readyState]);
        console.log("networkState = " + ns[video.networkState]);
        bufinfo();
      }

      function bufinfo() {
        // tr is a TimeRanges object
        tr = video.buffered
        if (tr.length > 0) {
          var ranges = ""
          for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            s = tr.start(i);
            e = tr.end(i);
            ranges += s + '-' + e;
            if (i + 1 < tr.length) {
              ranges += ', '
            }
          }
          console.log("buffered time ranges: " + ranges);
        }
      }

      video.onerror = function () {
        console.log(video.error);
      }

      video.oncanplay = function () {
        canplay = true;
        if (!playing) {
          console.log("canplay!");
          vinfo();
        }
      }

      var playing = false;
      function playfulfilled(v) {
        console.log("visible so playing " + video.currentSrc.split('/').pop());
        playing = true;
      }

      function playrejected(v) {
        console.log("play failed", v);
      }

      function setstate(visible) {
        if (canplay) {
          if (visible) {
            p = video.play();
            if (p !== undefined) {
              p.then(playfulfilled, playrejected);
            }
          } else if (playing) {
            video.pause();
            console.log("invisible so paused");
            playing = false;
          }
        } else {
          console.log("!canplay, visible:", visible);
          vinfo();
        }
      }
      // Because $watch calls $parse on the 1st arg, the property doesn't need to exist on first load
      scope.$parent.$watch('active', setstate);
    }
  };
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where the video worked on my desktop chrome, and desktop-mobile view, but not my iphone. Turns out i needed to add the "playsinline" property to the video tag. :]

Comment: Please be more descriptive or use comments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue fixed for me after switching off "Data saving" mode in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I spend all my afternoon to fix an autoplay problem on iOS and discovered you just to disable the "ECO MODE" or it won't play automatically.