# html5 video tag no playback

Tags: html, video, codec

I have some videos that I am trying to playback in an HTML5 script and I keep getting errors.  In Firefox it gives me "Video format or mime type not supported".

The format of the video is  MPEG Audio layer 1/2 (mp4a) and the Video is H264 - MPEG - 4 AVC part 10 AVC-1.  I have added the AddType for video/mp4 and audio/mp4 as well as well as the AddType setting for ogg and webm.

The `Curl -I` on the recordings show the following.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 18:34:55 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sat, 21 Jan 2017 21:52:56 GMT
ETag: "98b556c-546a1ca04c347"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 160126316
Content-Type: audio/mp4
```

The actual video tag that I am using looks like the following.

```
    <video controls="controls" poster="Images/Tux.svg.png" height="150"                  width="200"> 
      <source src="Videos/Part1demo.new.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
      <source src="Videos/Part1demo.new.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="Videos/Part1demo.new.ogv" type="video/ogg"> 
      </video>
```

I have tried converting the recordings using VLC and generating the additional sources without success.

When I load the page in IE11 it also seems like it does not recognize other HTML5 elements.  Is there something I need to add in a meta tag or header element?

Comment: I'd check the re-encode using ffmpeg (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351136/preparing-mp4-file-for-html-5/27362604#27362604), also just FYI the `controls` attribute is binary (if it's there they show, if not they don't, don't need the `="controls"` bit)

Comment: I have been pounding this and it still behaves the same.  More unusual is that I am developing the script in BlueGriffon and BlueGriffon has a built in light weight web browser based on Firefox and it runs fine in that.  When I run the site in my  Apache web server I get the Mime type not supported error in the same Firefox (and all Firefox builds.

Comment: converted the recording using the ffmpeg tool with the following syntax and got the same errors.

Comment: ffmpeg -i Part2demo.new.mp4 -f mp4 test2.mp4

Comment: The output from an mplayer execution does not fit in the dialog box.  It looks like I am restricted to 500 characters.  It does appear to be normal though.

Comment: do you have a snippet of the video you could post/share somewhere? also does your Apache server have relevant MIME types defined? http://www.html5videoplayer.net/html5video/html5-video-mime-types-setup-apache-iis-servers/

Comment: I have the relevant mime types added to the httpd.conf should they be in a particular section.  I do not have a FTP server where I can post this.

Comment: never mind.  I found the issue in the error.log and it was with a mod_security filter.  I have corrected that and am good.  Thanks,