# HTML5 Video not working on Safari

Tags: html, video, safari

I know the posts aren't missing on this subject but none of them was usefull to me so please bear with me. On my website I cannot play self hosted videos, it happens only with Safari and I was wondering why ? I tried to add `controls` to `true`, played with encoding and still nothing worked.

```
<video id="Video1" poster="../images/vr/vrslider.jpg" onclick="vidplay()">
    <source src="../images/vr/VR1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="../images/vr/VR1.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8, vorbis" />
    <source src="../images/vr/VR1.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora, vorbis" />
</video>
```

(I use javascript onclick to play the video)

It works with every other browser just not safari, there is another interesting fact I have multiple page where there are videos on my website it works in every page expect the full width `<video>` one (every page with videos use the same code), where is this problem coming from ?

Comment: what version of Safari? macOS or iOS? Can you point us to a sample that shows one of the failing videos? what happens why you try and play the video?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Both of them, when I click play the cover stay the button change to pause but the video doesn't start.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console or network (Develop menu). My guess would be an encoding issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351136/preparing-mp4-file-for-html-5/27362604#27362604 for ffmpeg parameters that usually work for me)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Just tried, unfortunately that wasn't the problem

Comment: Can you point us to a sample that shows one of the failing videos? what happens why you try and play the video