Large background video for a landing page takes a while to load
I'm pretty new to html/css, and I have a portfolio website that I coded for my UX design projects, which I host through digitalocean from github files.
My landing page background is a video, and it's a decently large video that takes up the whole screen. This obviously takes a while to load - right now it's just embedded as a video element in html.
I've tried compressing it, shortening it, etc, but it still takes a while to load for other people (not me, as I've loaded it so many times)
I'm wondering if there's any other way I can put this video here. I saw some things online about hosting the video somewhere else (ex. vimeo) and embedding it so it is automatically hosted somewhere else online. Would something like this work for a background video that auto plays and loops?
Is there any other place where I can host this video and have it stream to my website when users first load it?
How do most websites do this? I've seen plenty of landing pages for products that feature a large, high res video that loads instantly.
Thanks for the help

have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351136/preparing-mp4-file-for-html-5/27362604#27362604 for some optimisation suggestions. Having metadata at the front and a server that supports byte range requests are key

Like you mentioned in your post, hosting on another site is a must. You can use the iframe element to display your video in your webpage.
If you upload your video to youtube you can embed it in your page as such (enter a number only, i.e 1920 not 1920px):
<iframe width="your_width_px" height="your_height_px"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoIDhere">
</iframe>

and if you want to autoplay or start the video muted you can do so with these:
<iframe width="your_width_px" height="your_height_px"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoIDhere?autoplay=1&mute=1">
</iframe>

And to loop:
<iframe width="your_width_px" height="your_height_px"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoIDhere?loop=1>
</iframe>


Thanks, this is helpful. The only issue is, now there's youtube's UI still at the top and bottom of the screen. it seems there's no way to get rid of the youtube watermark in the bottom right corner. Trying to figure out a way around this

Look into the youtube iframe api. You can use this to play a video without the UI stuff.

yes, you can remove some elements, but not completely remove all watermarks so it's a blank video. I'm messing around with the div dimensions to cut them off

Have you got any links to a website that does what you want? Maybe use inspect element and try to work backwards from how they achieved it. Im sure there are many ways.
